# Why might DSBulk Load stop operation without any errors?

Tags: cassandra, datastax, cassandra-3.0, dsbulk, datastax-astra

I have created a Cassandra database in DataStax Astra and am trying to load a CSV file using DSBulk in Windows. However, when I run the dsbulk load command, the operation never completes or fails. I receive no error message at all, and I have to manually terminate the operation after several minutes. I have tried to wait it out, and have let the operation run for 30 minutes or more with no success.

I know that a free tier of Astra might run slower, but wouldn't I see at least some indication that it is attempting to load data, even if slowly?

When I run the command, this is the output that is displayed and nothing further:

```bash
C:\Users\JT\Desktop\dsbulk-1.8.0\bin>dsbulk load -url test1.csv -k my_keyspace -t test_table -b "secure-connect-path.zip" -u my_user -p my_password -header true
Username and password provided but auth provider not specified, inferring PlainTextAuthProvider
A cloud secure connect bundle was provided: ignoring all explicit contact points.
A cloud secure connect bundle was provided and selected operation performs writes: changing default consistency level to LOCAL_QUORUM.
Operation directory: C:\Users\JT\Desktop\dsbulk-1.8.0\bin\logs\LOAD_20210407-143635-875000
```

I know that DataStax recently changed Astra so that you need credentials from a generated Token to connect DSBulk, but I have a classic DB instance that won't accept those token credentials when entered in the dsbulk load command. So, I use my regular user/password.

When I check the DSBulk logs, the only text is the same output displayed in the console, which I have shown in the code block above.

If it means anything, I have the exact same issue when trying to run dsbulk Count operation.

I have the most recent JDK and have set both the `JAVA_HOME` and `PATH` variables.

I have also tried adding dsbulk/bin directory to my PATH variable and had no success with that either.

Do I need to adjust any settings in my Astra instance?

Lastly, is it possible that my basic laptop is simply not powerful enough for this operation or just running the operation crazy slow?

Any ideas or help is much appreciated!

Comment: Can you add "-verbosity 2" and check the output for anything usual? Also, you might want to ask this kind of questions on academy.datastax.com, as SO is usually not keen on questions about specific products like DSBulk.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I created a new Astra instance and everything worked. I think there are just some bugs with recent changes to Astra if you have an older account. And I will keep in mind not to post about specific products in future SO questions.Thanks again!

Comment: @jtdelato - what bugs are you running into with Astra? Happy to help get this figured out.

Comment: @AlexL - Not sure actually if they are truly bugs or just user error. However, I noticed that my Astra Classic DB freezes mid-operation in when trying to load data with DSBulk. I tried adding -verbosity 2 to my load operation but the only information provided is the current settings for Bulk Loader and DataStax Java Driver and the operation freezes after that. I also noticed that my Astra account from last year and a new account I created this week both do not have an "Add Service Account" option under the organization settings. Several people at a DS workshop this week also had that issue.